# Run logstash on demand

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Is it possible to run logstash on demand instead of streaming files? I have set of files placed in a folder, but I would like push only few of them on need basis to elasticsearch.

Is this even possible with logstash? I do have an option to do it programatically without using logstash. But considering the file size today (~10gb) and anticipated growth in future, I would like to see if logstash is an option here.

Comment: How about running Logstash manually whenever you need to stream your file(s)?

Comment: Logstash does not accept input file as argument. Hence doing manually will need to create different configurations. Also logstash does not stop once the processing is completed. I would need logstash to stop as soon as processing is done. Is there any way? Please suggest

Comment: You can always pipe the content of the file into Logstash using the `stdin` input: `cat myfile.txt | bin/logstash -f logstash.conf`, where `logstash.conf` defines `input { stdin{}}`

Comment: Thanks much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pipe the content of the file into Logstash using the stdin input:

```
cat myfile.txt | bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

where `logstash.conf` defines

```
input { 
    stdin{}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to [logstash-input-file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-path) for help.
To sepcify the files you want to monitor:

```
input{
    file{
        path => ["/var/log/messages","/var/log/nginx/access.log"]
    }
}
```

or,in you case ,you can also monitor a folder and exclude some file in it:

```
input{
    file{
        path => ["/var/log/nginx/*.log"]
        exclude => "error.log"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a standard configuration for streaming file. Running logstash with this instance will not stop once the access.log file processing is completed. It will wait forever to see if there are any modifications. I would like to know if there is any way to stop the process as soon as file processing is complete.